# Register Optional for JDBI

Tags: java, jdbc, guava, dao, jdbi

I got a `No container builder available for com.google.common.base.Optional` error.

Here is a fuller stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No container builder available for com.google.common.base.Optional
    at     org.skife.jdbi.v2.ContainerFactoryRegistry.createBuilderFor(ContainerFactoryRegistry.java:75)
    at org.skife.jdbi.v2.Query.first(Query.java:271)
    at     org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.ResultReturnThing$SingleValueResultReturnThing.result(ResultReturnThing.java:112)
    at org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.ResultReturnThing.map(ResultReturnThing.java:48)
    at org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.QueryHandler.invoke(QueryHandler.java:45)
    at org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.SqlObject.invoke(SqlObject.java:175)
    at org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.SqlObject$1.intercept(SqlObject.java:75)
    at org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.CloseInternalDoNotUseThisClass$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b270edb1.select(<generated>)
```

I have a DAO with an interface like this:

```
import com.google.common.base.Optional;

public interface MyDAO {
    @SqlQuery("something")
    Optional<Data> select();
}
```

Here is my data access layer unit test:

```
public class MyDAOTest {
    @Test
    public void shouldSelect() {
        DBI dbi = new DBI("jdbc:(something)", "something", "something");
        MyDAO myDAO = dbi.onDemand(MyDAO.class);
        Optional<Data> data = myDAO.select();
        assertFalse(data.absent());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Register [`io.dropwizard.jdbi.OptionalContainerFactory`](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-jdbi/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/jdbi/OptionalContainerFactory.java) if you are using `com.google.common.base.Optional` and get the error `No container builder available for com.google.common.base.Optional`.

Register [`io.dropwizard.java8.jdbi.OptionalContainerFactory`](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard-java8/blob/master/dropwizard-java8-jdbi/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/java8/jdbi/OptionalContainerFactory.java) if you are using `java.util.Optional` and get the error `No container builder available for java.util.Optional`.

I followed the instructions [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/lWaag6YIb30):

```
public class MyDAOTest {
@Test
public void shouldSelect() {
    DBI dbi = new DBI("jdbc:(something)", "something", "something");
    dbi.registerContainerFactory(new OptionalContainerFactory());
    ...
}
```

Comment: Just to provide an update, the correct factory to register is now http://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.0/dropwizard-jdbi/apidocs/index.html?io/dropwizard/jdbi/GuavaOptionalContainerFactory.html for com.google.common.base.Optional.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that you're creating a new `io.dropwizard.java8.jdbi.DBIFactory`, not `io.dropwizard.jdbi.DBIFactory`, in your test code.  Unfortunately these have the same name and are (from my experience) easy to miss in the imports.

Comment: This answer is what [dropwizard-java8-jdbi documentation](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard-java8/blob/6c52af14b33c2ec52daea6b40ff3954e68b61107/README.md#jdbi) suggests.